# Google Photo changing resolution

Tags: google-photos

Using Google photo with "High quality" setting I'm having all my photos compressed to 12MP even if every photo is shooted from a Nexus 6P. (16Mp)

I'm asking this since the app is supposed to change the resolution only over 16Mp.

Why is this happening?

EDIT:

My bad. Nexus 6p has a 12Mp sensor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Google photo high quality pictures compressed even if they're under 16 megapixels?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111628/are-google-photo-high-quality-pictures-compressed-even-if-theyre-under-16-megap)

Comment: Related [Record video in QHD then reduce to FHD is the same thing of record in FHD](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171128/record-video-in-qhd-then-reduce-to-fhd-is-the-same-thing-of-record-in-fhd/171131#171131)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the photos generated by the camera are slightly over the limit that Google Photos checks. MP ratings are really ballparks.